# snap if present (run hook "configure": cannot locate base snap core22: No such file or directory

Tags: mysql-workbench, ubuntu-22.04

everyone. I have recently switched to Linux, especially Ubuntu, and I am facing trouble at every step. I have successfully configured the MySQL server, and now I am trying to install MySQL Workbench, but I am encountering an issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdiq5.png)

I have recently switched to Linux, especially Ubuntu, and I am facing trouble at every step. I have successfully configured the MySQL server, and now I am trying to install MySQL Workbench, but I am encountering an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today and I had to uninstall all snaps. The order matters, apps first then the base stuff and snapd last. Then apt purge snapd, and reinstall snapd. After that you can re-add the apps. A major pain in the neck but it worked. Cudos  to ravage.